# Запятая в ССП, - что-то мешает её поставить. Что?

Tags: пунктуация, ссп, запятые

> – Романы на съёмочной площадке возникают постоянно. Это то же самое,
>   что на любой работе. У тебя в редакции, например, наверняка есть люди,
>   которые тебе нравятся. Но амурных отношений на съёмках у меня не было
>   никогда. Я не считаю, что актёр – достойная профессия для мужчины.
>   **Есть, конечно, единицы-исключения, но в общем у меня к ним уважения нет (ЗНАК?) и, следовательно, любви не возникает.**

Comment: "Единицы-исключения" — это словотворчество? В сети можно найти "единицы, исключения", но в Нацкорпусе и этого нет, есть только "единичные исключения".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Запятая в ССП, - что-то мешает её поставить. Что?

Интонация. Запятая не была бы нужна и в отсутствие наречия "в общем":

*Есть, конечно, единицы-исключения, **но у меня к ним уважения нет и, следовательно, любви не возникает.***

Выделенную ***жирным*** часть можно, думаю, рассматривать как безличное предложение с однородными сказуемыми *"нет"* и *"не возникает"*, соединёнными союзом ***"и"***.

И даже если считать это предложение сложносочинённым, запятая не будет нужна в связи с наличием у частей этого предложения общих второстепенных членов: *"у меня"* и *"к ним"*.

Answer (score 4):

Есть, конечно, единицы-исключения, но **в общем** у меня к ним уважения нет и, следовательно, любви не возникает.

Общий элемент ― наречие **в общем**, поэтому нет запятой. Есть сомнения насчет вводного слова, но интонационно два последних предложения читаются как одна фраза.

Answer (score 2):

Если присмотреться, то получается, что в этом предложении соединились аж три случая, при которых запятая в ССП не ставится:

1. Общее обстоятельство ***в общем***;
2. Общее дополнение ***у меня***;
3. Оба предложения - "***У меня к ним уважения нет***" и "***У меня к ним любви не возникает***" - являются односоставными безличными.

Comment: Дорогой Человек! Моя ЛОшка металась-разрывалась между твоим и Славиным аналитическими ответами... Следующая - твоя, приходи!